# getting product by product_id

Tags: magento-1.7, product, product-collection

I am trying to get product by product_id without using load($product_id) (because load() may take much time) so ,i would like to get product from the product collection using product_id.

Which is the best way to get product in magento?(including minimum execution time)

Please help me anyone!..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');//or just an array with the attributes you need.
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $productId); //filter only the the id you need.
$product = $collection->getFirstItem();
```

But there might be some events that are dispatched only when loading the product. Getting it like this won't dispatch events like `catalog_product_load_after`, `catalog_product_load_before` and there might be others.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Mr.Marius..Why you have given the event "catalog_product_load_before" two times, so one is the after event right?.

Comment: @user3804631. Sorry. Copy paste error. The second one is `catalog_product_load_after`. I fixed it.

Comment: Mr.Marius This result give the product but it wont have its attribute and its value..how i can fetch that from this collection result..

Comment: It should have the attribute values for the attributes you passed as param to `addAttributeToSelect`

Comment: Thank you  @Marius  .It works after using addAttributeToSelect .